# Download a XML file via jsf

Tags: xml, jsf, download

I am trying to download XMLs file zipped as an archive using richfaces. I have done the usual way of downloading files. I have a requirement to download zip with .xlsx files. This same piece of code is working for zipped archive of xlsx files.

I have a throwDownload() that is as follows..

```
  public void throwDownload(ByteArrayOutputStream baos, String fileName) throws IOException {

    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext
            .getResponse();


    response.reset();
    response.setContentType("application/zip");
    response.setContentLength( baos.size() );
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
            + fileName + "\"");

    BufferedOutputStream output = null;
    final int buffersize = 20480;

    output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(),
            buffersize);
    output.write(baos.toByteArray());

    facesContext.responseComplete();

}
```

The same code works fine for zip containing .xlsx files. For zip containing .xml files the Save as dialog is shown the browser but downloaded file is having zero bytes. The response headers in fiddler for the two requests are as follows:

XML Files zip:-

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-disposition: attachment; filename="CRS_Files.zip"
Content-Type: application/zip
Content-Length: 1426
Date: Sun, 06 Apr 2014 14:42:50 GMT
```

XLSX Files zip:-

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-disposition: attachment; filename="DataCheckReports.zip"
Content-Type: application/zip
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sun, 06 Apr 2014 15:00:37 GMT
```

Comment: You should be `flush()`ing your buffered streams. Add `output.flush()` after `output.write()`

Comment: You're welcome. I'll post an answer later